# Trying to use @media queries to resize images for phone, tablet desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I'm having difficulty making the background images on my site responsive. I've added media queries to my page but they don't work and I'm not sure what else to do. Below, I've listed the html & css for the three images. Please advise any suggestions, thank you!

```css
body {
    background: url(/img/sect-bkgrd.jpg) center/cover fixed no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

#header {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 94px);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url(/img/sushi-main.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-color: #000;
}

#menu {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), url(/img/menu-bkgrd.jpg) center/cover fixed no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row height-90 align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="banner text-center">
                    <h1 class="display-1 text-capitalize underline w-50 mx-auto">
                        <strong class="primary-color">Title</strong>
                        <img src="/img/sushi-logo2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section id="menu" class="py-5 my-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!--        title-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h1 class="primary-color text-uppercase">sushi</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--         title-->
                    <!--          single item-->
                    <div class="single-item d-flex justify-content-between my-3 p-3">
                        <div class="single-item-text">
                            <h2 class="text-uppercase text-black">sushi</h2>
                            <h4 class="text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-item-price align-self-end">
                            <h1 class="text-uppercase text-black">$10</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use max-width or min-width property to resize your background image for multiple devices. For example, for small devices, the media query will be

```
@media screen & (max-width:768px){
#img{
max-width: 100%;
}

}
```